# Cannot figure out DNS Master Error:

Tags: domain-name-system, slave, master

I am attempting to use zone transfer between my Master and Slave DNS servers however I am unable to start my named service and receive the following error:

```
[root@balsam named]# systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-03-11 14:43:58 EST; 7s ago
  Process: 2510 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/rndc stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2440 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2550 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2443 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: dns_rdata_fromtext: mydb-for-172.30.20:16: near 'pine.coniferous.trees.ops.': not a valid number
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: zone 20.30.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file mydb-for-172.30.20 failed: not a valid number
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: zone 20.30.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: _default/20.30.172.in-addr.arpa./IN: not a valid number
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: zone ajfoncec.org/IN: loaded serial 2016010301
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops bash[2550]: zone 62.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2016010301
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Mar 11 14:43:58 balsam.coniferous.trees.ops systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

What does this mean? I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the zone files its mentioning:

mydb-for-172.30.20

```
$TTL    3D
@       IN      SOA     balsam.coniferous.trees.ops.      pine.coniferous.trees.ops.(
                2016010301       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                1W      ; Expire
                1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@           IN      NS      balsam.coniferous.trees.ops.
1           IN  PTR larch.coniferous.trees.ops.
2           IN      PTR     balsam.coniferous.trees.ops.
3                       IN      PTR     spruce.coniferous.trees.ops.
5                       IN      PTR     pine.coniferous.trees.ops.
6                       IN      PTR     fir.coniferous.trees.ops.
8                       IN      PTR     bristlecone.coniferous.trees.ops.
5           IN  MX  pine.coniferous.trees.ops.
```

and the other one mydb-for-ajfoncec-org

```
$TTL    3D
@       IN      SOA     vm1.ajfoncec.org.      hostmaster.ajfoncec.org.(
                2016010301       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                1W      ; Expire
                1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@       IN      NS      vm1.ajfoncec.org.
vm1     IN      A       192.168.62.2
vm2     IN      A       192.168.62.3
vm3     IN      A       192.168.62.4
host    IN      A       192.168.62.1
```

oh and the mydb-for-coniferous-trees-ops

```
$TTL    3D
@       IN      SOA     balsam.coniferous.trees.ops.      pine.coniferous.trees.ops.(
                2016010301       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                1W      ; Expire
                1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@       IN      NS      balsam.coniferous.trees.ops.
balsam  IN      A       172.30.20.2
spruce  IN  A   172.30.20.3
pine    IN  A   172.30.20.5
fir IN  A   172.30.20.6
bristlecone IN  A   172.30.20.8
larch   IN  A   172.30.20.1
pine    IN  MX  0   172.30.20.5
```

Comment: Use the "edit" tool to add information to your question, not the answer or comment field.

Answer (score 2):

Delete this line from below PTR records:

```
5           IN  MX  pine.coniferous.trees.ops.
```

Firstly, reverse zones don't need MX records, no one will be sending an email to such address. Secondly, it's malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Your MX record for `pine.coniferous.trees.ops.` lacks the priority number. And it's useless to begin with, this is a reverse zone.

Please take the time to read error messages and to think about them....

There might be further errors, but I've stopped reading at the first error message. Check your files again.